# salesforce uploading to S3

Tags: salesforce

Our app directory upload images to S3 from client side and on success we store the url to custom object in salesforce. However I saw a lot of people are indirectly upload images to S3 through salesforce using AWS API. I wonder if my approach pass through the salesforce security review.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Its about Salesforce Limits.**

If you upload files to AWS via Salesforce, you will not be able to upload files more than 5MB as salesforce can accept files upto 5MB only. By directly uploading to AWS S3, you dont need to worry about this limit anymore.

**2. Its Easy.**

Uploading files to AWS is very easy science Amazon provides required APIs to do it. You must be knowing difficulties of working in Salesforce Environment while doing this.

**3. Its More Secure**

S3 provides all possible kind of security features possible. Directing files from Salesforce will make process slow and less secure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the stuff. I am also wondering it this pass the security review for salesforce appexchange

Comment: @Shinya Koizumi Yes, There is a 'Force.com Toolkit for Amazon Web Services' App available on AppExchange.

Comment: The tool is in a way different because it still pass through the salesforce. In my app the file is posted to aws directoy with Jquery file uploader using javascript. However we saved the url to the custom object so that it should be retrieved from s3.

Comment: In the tool, there are two ways of uploading file. You are write about one, look at another. I have used it multiple times.